# Changing allowed string value in obfuscated code

Tags: javascript

I have this obfuscated code. I just want to change one thing. Since this is a summary code for Blogger, it allows 40 words to be shown in the summary. I want it to be 0 words. All my tries were unsuccessful. I don't know how to deal with obfuscated code. Can anyone help me setting the string value to 0?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[


eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('C X(s,n){14 s["\\9\\2\\i\\5\\8\\d\\2"](/<.*?>/15,"")["\\b\\i\\5\\c\\3"](/\\s+/)["\\b\\5\\c\\d\\2"](0,n-1)["\\N\\g\\c\\h"]("\\j")};C 16(a){13 p=S["\\6\\2\\3\\E\\5\\2\\7\\2\\h\\3\\y\\w\\M\\v"](a),z="",G=p["\\6\\2\\3\\E\\5\\2\\7\\2\\h\\3\\b\\y\\w\\D\\8\\6\\Q\\8\\7\\2"]("\\c\\7\\6");U(G["\\5\\2\\h\\6\\3\\e"]>=1){z="\\t\\c\\7\\6\\j\\d\\5\\8\\b\\b\\u\\f\\o\\8\\5\\b\\8\\7\\f\\j\\b\\9\\d\\u\\f"+G[0]["\\b\\9\\d"]+"\\f\\j\\4\\r"}Y{z="\\t\\c\\7\\6\\j\\d\\5\\8\\b\\b\\u\\f\\o\\8\\5\\b\\8\\7\\f\\j\\b\\9\\d\\u\\f\\e\\3\\3\\i\\B\\4\\4\\I\\k\\o\\i\\k\\o\\5\\g\\6\\b\\i\\g\\3\\k\\d\\g\\7\\4\\Z\\10\\2\\O\\q\\q\\v\\18\\q\\3\\i\\L\\4\\K\\2\\L\\17\\W\\1d\\E\\1f\\1g\\1h\\M\\4\\l\\l\\l\\l\\l\\l\\l\\l\\y\\m\\K\\4\\H\\w\\1b\\A\\Q\\9\\P\\O\\P\\A\\H\\4\\b\\I\\19\\J\\J\\4\\h\\g\\12\\c\\7\\8\\6\\2\\k\\N\\i\\6\\f\\j\\4\\r"};p["\\c\\h\\h\\2\\9\\V\\D\\A\\R"]="\\t\\8\\j\\e\\9\\2\\F\\u\\f"+x+"\\f\\r"+z+"\\t\\4\\8\\r"+X(p["\\c\\h\\h\\2\\9\\V\\D\\A\\R"],1a)};$(S)["\\9\\2\\8\\v\\w"](C(){$("\\T\\d\\9\\2\\v\\c\\3")["\\e\\3\\7\\5"]("\\t\\8\\j\\e\\9\\2\\F\\u\\f\\e\\3\\3\\i\\B\\4\\4\\m\\m\\m\\k\\o\\5\\g\\6\\6\\2\\9\\3\\e\\2\\7\\2\\q\\k\\d\\g\\7\\4\\f\\r\\y\\5\\g\\6\\6\\2\\9\\3\\e\\2\\7\\2\\q\\t\\4\\8\\r");1c(C(){U(!$("\\T\\d\\9\\2\\v\\c\\3\\B\\W\\c\\b\\c\\o\\5\\2")["\\5\\2\\h\\6\\3\\e"]){1e["\\5\\g\\d\\8\\3\\c\\g\\h"]["\\e\\9\\2\\F"]="\\e\\3\\3\\i\\B\\4\\4\\m\\m\\m\\k\\o\\5\\g\\6\\6\\2\\9\\3\\e\\2\\7\\2\\q\\k\\d\\g\\7\\4"}},11)});',62,80,'||x65|x74|x2F|x6C|x67|x6D|x61|x72||x73|x69|x63|x68|x22|x6F|x6E|x70|x20|x2E|x41|x77||x62||x39|x3E||x3C|x3D|x64|x79||x42|imgtag|x4D|x3A|function|x54|x45|x66|img|x6B|x31|x30|x55|x38|x49|x6A|x32|x53|x4E|x4C|document|x23|if|x48|x76|stripTags|else|x2D|x51|3000|x2B|var|return|ig|readmore|x4A|x58|x36|42|x47|setInterval|x43|window|x34|x57|x35'.split('|'),0,{}))
//]]></script>
```

Thanks to commenters, I see that a first step is to pass the code through jsbeautifier.org using the option "Unescape printable chars encoded as \xNN or \uNNNN".

```
function stripTags(s, n) {
    return s["replace"](/<.*?>/ig, "")["split"](/\s+/)["slice"](0, n - 1)["join"](" ")
};

function readmore(a) {
    var p = document["getElementById"](a),
        imgtag = "",
        img = p["getElementsByTagName"]("img");
    if (img["length"] >= 1) {
        imgtag = "<img class=\"balsam\" src=\"" + img[0]["src"] + "\" />"
    } else {
        imgtag = "<img class=\"balsam\" src=\"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Qe299dX9tp8/Ue8JvCE4W5I/AAAAAAAABwU/kyGMNrS2SMk/s1600/no+image.jpg\" />"
    };
    p["innerHTML"] = "<a href=\"" + x + "\">" + imgtag + "</a>" + stripTags(p["innerHTML"], 42)
};
$(document)["ready"](function () {
    $("#credit")["html"]("<a href=\"http://www.bloggertheme9.com/\">Bloggertheme9</a>");
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!$("#credit:visible")["length"]) {
            window["location"]["href"] = "http://www.bloggertheme9.com/"
        }
    }, 3000)
});
```

Now where do I change the allowed number of words?

Comment: thanks, as i was doing it and it told me that you already did it :)

Comment: jsbeautifier is your friend.. How and this code is not what you think (it add some kind of credit). Edited the question to add unobfuscated code

Comment: its javascript , RC what do you mean?

Comment: how did you unobfuscated it? i searched alot for this, but will i dont think its what i was expecting but anyway this is great

Comment: jsbeautifier dot org (for example)

Comment: well i tried it it wasnt the same , i mean it just beautify the script , anyways i dont think the first part is in your code though
<code>
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}]
</code>

Comment: @user3289647 I edited your question to say what I think you want. Please revise it as you see fit.